# NameNotFoundException Scheduler TaskHandler EJB lookup in WAS 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1

I have started getting this following error repetitively. I have checked ejb-jar.xml & ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml thoroughly and both have correct information about EJB home, remote, jndi name against the ejb-name. What else could be the reason ?  Please help.

NamingException caught in  XXXXXXXX : "Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound"

Comment: That's a generic exception.  Please include the full exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Scheduler uses a config XML where we can declare different TaskHandler EJBs with jndi name. Whiel formatting the XML we accidentally put a space before the jndi name. Though we were expecting that WAS will trim the spaces :(

Anyway thanks.